# Defining main() in python

Tags: python

Often, I see the following code in python programs

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm following the [Python class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/introduction.html) on Google Code, and it says that it's standard boilerplate code.

Do I really need to write such code in all my scripts?

What functionality would this add to my programs?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to, but it's invaluable for things like unit testing.

You can create a `main` in every python file so that, if you run it directly, `__name__` will be set to `"__main__"` and it will run a barrage of tests on the code in question.

If you just import it normally from *another* program, that doesn't happen, because `__name__` is set to a different value.

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful, when you're importing the files. You can either run the python file as a standalone program, or import some components of it into another programs.